# C# Class Library within VB Solution Does Not Import

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class-library

I am attempting to create a C# class library for some Yahoo Placefinder work. I did not find VB code examples online, so I thought I would use the C# code they provide and simply add another class library project to my solution and save myself some time.

However, no matter what I do, I can't seem to get my VB windows service project to recognize the imports namespace.

[image: Imports Code]

I have repeatedly added referenced within the VB windows service project to the C# library (see below)...

[image: References]

...but nothing seems to cause it to recognize it properly.

Below is the class code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OAuth;

namespace YahooRequest
{
  public class YahooR
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Request Address from Yahoo BOSS Placefinder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string RequestAddress(string[] args)
    {
      string consumerKey = "...";
      string consumerSecret = "...";
      var uri = new Uri("https://yboss.yahooapis.com/geo/placefinder?location=" + args[0]);
      string url, param;
      var oAuth = new OAuthBase(); 
      var nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
      var timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
      var signature = oAuth.GenerateSignature(uri, consumerKey,
      consumerSecret, string.Empty, string.Empty, "GET", timeStamp, nonce,
      OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out url, out param);

      using (WebRequest response = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}?{1}&oauth_signature={2}",
      url, param, signature)).GetResponse())
      {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
          return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this library simply won't be recognized by Visual Studio?

**UPDATE 1**

A comment directed me to look at the object viewer, which does have the class library displayed, it does not show any functions. I'm not sure why this is, but I feel like it has something to do with my problem.

[image: Object Viewer]

**UPDATE 2**

Code originally came from [Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/oauth.html).

Comment: What version of the framework does your library target, and what version does your VB project target?

Comment: I had thought about that. Both target 2.0. The original project is old, so I built the class library to match. The class library compiles with no problems.

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: Was `System.Linq` part of 2.0?

Comment: Likewise `System.Threading.Tasks`. This really doesn't look like a .NET 2.0 project.

Comment: Wouldn't I get compilation errors if the DLL wasn't able to build? Also, as a test, I changed the target framework for the projects in my solution from 2.0 to 3.5. Class library built, but the VB project still does not recognize the namespace.

Comment: Add `CLSCompliant(true)` to the AssemblyInfo.cs of your C# class library project, build and look for warnings.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie - Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped. No errors.

Comment: Does your VB project by chance have a winform or class named YahooRequest?  That could create ambiguity as you have a class and namespace named the same.  I just reproduced the problem doing that.

Comment: @eric1825, I just did a Find All In Solution and only 4 instances of YahooRequest appeared. 3 are in the Class Library, and one is in the Imports line that isn't working.

Comment: @QuantumDynamix Does `YahooRequest` appear in the [Object Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (at all vs under "My Solution")? Can you browse it?

Comment: @QuantumDynamix Look out Warnings from the Error List window, not the build results from the Output window.  If the library is marked as CLSCompliant, it will display Warnings if there are any visible objects which are not CLS compliant.

Comment: @GSerg, it does appear, but there does not seem to be any classes or functions available. That seems odd, right?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie, This is the only thing in the warnings: 

'YahooRequest' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Everything looks like it should have a public member, but maybe that is where the error lies.

Comment: A couple of things: You have a class with only one public static member. Maybe you should make the class static as well, might have implications for CLSCompliant. Another thing is to check to see if you have a warning for the reference in your references list under your VB project. It may not be finding the DLL.

Comment: I cannot compile the C# code, not even under FW 4.5. Some more `using`s are required, the `WebRequest` does not implement `IDisposable` and does not contain a definition of `GetResponseStream`. Under FW 3.5 there's also an error about `System.Threading.Tasks`. Are you sure the C# project builds at all?

Comment: I uploaded the class to GibHub (see question update). Hopefully that will help clarify.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought - all cs files in the project have Build Action type of `Content`. Change that to `Compile`.

Comment: @GSerg /FACEPALM! How did I not know that existed!?!?! Thank you so much! This solved my problem and allowed me to get back to work after nearly a day of lost time. Feel free to submit your comments as an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: Huge thank you to everyone that supplied comments! You are all amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Studio complains the referenced library contains no public classes or methods, that is most likely true.

- Check that the library project indeed builds. Use 'Build' > 'Clean solution', then rebuild.
- Check that you are referencing the correct dll file from the main project. You might have pointed the reference to some stale copy.
- Check that code modules that contain actual library code indeed compile (the Build Action type must be 'Compile').

  [image]

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your project is selected and then go to projects and click on "Add Reference" to to import your Class Library